# Why can many (most?) R functions loop over a vector but some do not?

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply, sapply

Many functions in R will take a vector as an argument, evaluate the function for each element of the argument vector, and then return a vector containing the results. For example, if I create the following function

```
myFunction <- function(x) {
  x <- (x+1)/2
  print(x)
}
```

and then evaluate `myFunction(1:5)`, I get a vector result: `1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0.` No loop is required.

The other day, however, I was using the `dir.create()` function in order to make a bunch of directories. The `dir.create()` function takes as an argument the path of the folder that you want to create. Since I wanted to make many folders, I tried to use a character vector with each element being the path of a folder that I wanted to create:

```
dir.create(c("folder 1 path", "folder 2 path", "folder 3 path"))
```

On doing this, I get an error that says, "invalid 'path' argument." Sure enough, if you look at the documentation for `dir.create()`, it specifies that the path argument must be, "a character vector containing a single path name." 
The only way to make `dir.create()` accept a vector of path names seems to be to write a loop or an apply function:

```
sapply(c("folder 1 path", "folder 2 path", "folder 3 path"), dir.create)
```

Although I can't remember specific examples, I think I've run into other functions like this. It seems inconsistent that some functions automatically loop over a vector of inputs while others behave like the `dir.create()` function. Writing a loop is easy enough but I'd really like to understand why it is that I expect some functions to operate over the length of a vector and yet they do not.

Is there any way to tell ahead of time whether a function is happy to take a vector as an input or whether it will only accept a single value?

Comment: The best way to know ahead of time, other than through experience, is probably to read the function documentation. But you can also vectorise functions, e.g. `Vectorize(dir.create)(paths)`.

Comment: There are no scalars in R, so all functions "take vectors". What you mean is whether a function is vectorised or not.

Comment: Thanks to the above for your help. I guess my follow up questions would be: how would one write a function that is not vectorized and why would one want to do this? In my example above "myFunction()", I didn't have to do anything special to make it vectorized. It just "works" for a vector of any length. So presumably if I wanted to write an unvectorized function I would have to do something special, correct?

Comment: `F <- function(x) { if (length(x) > 1) { stop(<informative error message>) } #...}`

Comment: These might be worth a read: [Vectorization in R: Why?](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html); [The Relationship between Vectorized and Devectorized Code](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/22/the-relationship-between-vectorized-and-devectorized-code/)

Comment: This is one of the major reasons why we have documentation ;-)

Comment: @jbaums Great link. Thanks. A key paragraph in there is the one ending with, "What makes vectorization in R effective is that it provides a mechanism for moving computations into C, where a hidden layer of devectorization can do its mgic [sic]". It's in the section titled "The reversed role of vectorization in R and Julia".

Comment: The Julia vs R article is so wrong and the comparisons so unfair that shouldn't be taken seriously.